# Not finding url's for REST services in Java

Tags: java, rest, servlets

There are many posts relating to creating REST services and I have read dozens of them;  I am still unable to reach my service.  My service creates (via PUT or POST) and return (via GET) Offerror's - which have an id, name and address.  An Offer is a class, Offerrors a class holding the instances of Offerror in a ConcurrentMap and OfferrorServlet is the servlet class.  Please help me straighten out my REST coding; I would rather annotate classes than configure a web.xml.

To run I deploy the artifact OfferorWebService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war to JBoss.  I test via PostMan, with Accepting & Content-type of application/json set and authenticating with admin account

GET http://localhost:8080/OfferorWebService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/offerrors () produces "404 not found"

POST http://localhost:8080/OfferorWebService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/offerrors produces "405 Method not allowed"

What do I need to add/change in my servlet or calls?  Do I need additional configuration files? Thanks!

in pom.xml

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
            <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src.main.java</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
       <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>3.6.1</version>
             <configuration>
                 <source>1.8</source>
                 <target>1.8</target>
             </configuration>
         </plugin>      
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

OfferrorServlet.java (I have removed code that has been commented out for brevity)

```
@WebServlet("/Offerrors")
public class OfferorServlet extends HttpServlet {
    
       static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       static final ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
       Offerors mapOfOfferors; 
       
        @Override
        public void init() {
            mapOfOfferors = new Offerors();
            mapOfOfferors.setServletContext(this.getServletContext());
        }

        // GET /offeror or /offeror?id=123
        @Override
        @GET  
        public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
            String param = request.getParameter("id");
            Integer key = (param == null) ? null : Integer.valueOf((param.trim()));
     
            // return an Offeror
            try {
                    sendResponse(response, om.writeValueAsString(mapOfOfferors.getOfferror(key)));                  

            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @POST  // /offerors
        @Override
        public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
            String name = request.getParameter("name");
            String address = request.getParameter("address");
            String msg = "Creating an offeror";
            if (name == null || address == null)
                throw new RuntimeException(Integer.toString(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST));

            Offeror offeror = new Offeror();
            // Save the ID of the newly created Offeror.
            offeror.setName(name);
            offeror.setAddress(address);
            int id = mapOfOfferors.addOfferor(offeror);

            try {
                sendResponse(response, om.writeValueAsString(msg));
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // Longer PUT method removed for brevity

        // Methods Not Allowed
        @Override
        public void doTrace(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
            throw new RuntimeException(Integer.toString(HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED));
        }

... (many more of the same)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I guess you must not use these annotations combined with servlets, they are not designed for it and I think that will not work properly, doGet, doPut, doTrace, doPost will do the work well, if you wanna use java libs focused on rest services with more features you should research about jaxRS or jaxWS docs, howTo's, servlets are more focused on the basic http iteractions and with jsp and this model, but of course you can do with plain servlets, just remove these annotations and give a feedback of what happened.

Comment: Thanks.  I got it to work,  I will post on that later